# pandas : pd.concat results in duplicated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of large dataframes in a list. I concatenate all of them to produce a single large dataframe.

```
df_list # This contains a list of dataframes
result = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
result.columns.duplicated().any() # This returns True
```

My expectation was that pd.concat will not produce duplicate columns.

I want to understand when it could result in duplicate columns so that I can debug the source.

I could not reproduce the problem with a toy dataset.

I have verified that the input data frames have unique columns by running `df.columns.duplicated().any()`.

The pandas version used 1.0.1

```
(Pdb) p result_data[0].columns.duplicated().any()
False
(Pdb) p result_data[1].columns.duplicated().any()
False
(Pdb) p result_data[2].columns.duplicated().any()
False
(Pdb) p result_data[3].columns.duplicated().any()
False
(Pdb) p pd.concat(result_data[0:4]).columns.duplicated().any()
True
```

Comment: if you have duplicated columns when concating on `axis=0` as shown in your code `pd.concat(df_list)` , it can mean one or more of the dataframe in `df_list` has duplicate column names. you can loop your last code to each element in the `df_list` to find that dataframe. `[df.columns.duplicated().any() for df in df_list]`

Comment: @anky Yes. I did that already. All source dataframes have unique columns -- verified.

Answer (score 7):

Check the below behaviour:

```
In [452]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,3,4]})                                                                                                                                                    

In [468]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,4,5]})

In [460]: df_list = [df1,df2]
```

This concats and keeps duplicate columns:

```
In [463]: pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[474]: 
   A  B  A  B
0  1  2  1  2
1  2  3  2  4
2  3  4  3  5
```

**`pd.concat` always concatenates the dataframes as is. It does not drop duplicate columns at all.**

If you concatenate without the axis, it will append one dataframe below another in the same columns.

So you can have duplicate rows now, but not columns.

```
In [477]: pd.concat(df_list)                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[477]: 
   A  B
0  1  2  ## duplicate row
1  2  3
2  3  4
0  1  2  ## duplicate row
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

You can remove these duplicate rows by using `drop_duplicates()`:

```
In [478]: pd.concat(df_list).drop_duplicates()                                                                                                                                                              
Out[478]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

**Update after OP's comment:**

```
In [507]: df_list[0].columns.duplicated().any()                                                                                                                                                             
Out[507]: False

In [508]: df_list[1].columns.duplicated().any()                                                                                                                                                             
Out[508]: False

In [510]: pd.concat(df_list[0:2]).columns.duplicated().any()                                                                                                                                                
Out[510]: False
```

Comment: Mayank: I am seeing duplicate columns with axis=0 as default.

Comment: Like how? Can you paste that in the question?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The case which you are saying is pretty weird. Please take a subset of your dataframes and check properly. There has to be something that is getting missed.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for some clue on when this can happen as the frames are pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

If the column names are the same and axis = 0 (default) then the columns should be combined. I'll bet your column names are actually different due to something like leading spaces or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I get data from IEXCloud. I used IEXFinance functions to grab different data sets which are all suppose to return dataframes. I then Use concat to join the dataframes. It looks to have repeated the first column (symbols) into column 97. The data in columns 96 and 98 where from the second dataframe. There are no duplicate columns in df1 or df2. I can't see any logical reason for duplicating it there. DF2 has 70 columns.I suspect some of what was returned as a 'dataframe' is something else but this doesnt explain the seeming random nature of the position the concat function chooses to duplicate the first column of the first df!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue and fixed it:
I tried to combine data extracted from a Microsoft SQL database (using sqlite3 and pyodbc) and data extracted from an Oracle database (using cx_Oracle and sqlalchemy).
After combining them with pd.concat, I ended up with two columns being duplicated.
Data from the Oracle extract only appeared in the second occurrence of these columns.
I observed that the headers I had defined for the two concerned columns in both SQL statements had only capital letters, while the duplicated columns' names came up spelled in small letters.
Apparently, in the results of the Oracle SQL query, the columns names with ONLY capital letters are transformed to names with small letters.
So, for these two columns, I had capital letters in the first dataset, but small letters in the second dataset.
It was not easy to notice because of my high number of columns, and the column names in both my SQL statements being all identical!
I fixed it by changing the column names in both SQL statements to names using both capital AND small letters.